# How to get vim to indent tcl properly?

Tags: vim, tcl, indentation

I have the following sample tcl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc main {} {
    foreach v $::argv {
        puts $v
}
}

main
```

When I get vim to indent this code (`ggVG=`), it indents exactly as above, which is obviously wrong as the braces do not match up.

However, I'm pretty sure my vim is set up properly:

```
:set
--- Options ---
  autoindent          backspace=2         expandtab           hlsearch            scroll=22           syntax=tcl          wildmenu
  autoread            comments=:#         filetype=tcl        incsearch           shiftround          ttyfast             window=0
  background=dark     commentstring=#%s   helplang=en         modelines=0         shiftwidth=4        ttymouse=xterm2   nowrap
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  formatoptions=tcroql
  indentexpr=GetTclIndent()
  indentkeys=0{,0},!^F,o,O,0]
```

and

```
:scriptnames
...
 52: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/tcl.vim
 53: /usr/share/vim/vim80/indent/tcl.vim
 54: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/tcl.vim
...
```

Is this just how vim indents tcl, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you are having. Just downloaded vim from their website and copied the exact code and it was indented fine with `ggVG=`.

Comment: try start your vim without plugins and settings `vim -u NONE`, it it works start doing binary search.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your example with a old Vim 7.4 and I see the same error. Then I tried it with Vim 8.1 and it works as it should. I checked `indent/tcl.vim` and it was updated 2018-12-05 (Vim 8.1.0576).

Download the [current indent file from git](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/indent/tcl.vim). And store it in the directory `~/.vim/indent` (or `$HOME/vimfiles/indent` on Windows).

Restart Vim and test.

As soon as you update to Vim 8.1.0576 or later you can delete `indent/tcl.vim` from your personal config.

BTW: Only the indent file was updated. The scripts for syntax, compiler and ftplugin stayed the same.

PS: To save you one key-press: Try `gg=G` :-)